# Comparing float values in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, floating-point

My if expression always evaluates to TRUE somehow.
ROTATION variable is 0.000 or 90.000, a float value or it seems so

```
ROTATION="$(mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Rotation%" $VIDEO$ORIGINALEXTENTION)"
echo $ROTATION

ROTATION_PARAMETER=""

if [ $ROTATION -eq 90 ]
then
    ROTATION_PARAMETER=" --rotate=4"
fi

echo $ROTATION_PARAMETER
```

How can I compare a variable to a value?

Comment: `bash` can handle only integers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bc command for this puspose:

```
echo "$ROTATION == 90"|bc
```

and you will get 0 in case of false and 1 in case of true

P.S. Be aware that comparing for equivalence floating point numbers is not the wisest thing in programming :)

Comment: You can use: `if [ $(echo "$ROTATION == 90" | bc) -eq 1 ]`

Comment: @jofel, the good practice is to make it on this way: if [ "$(echo "$ROTATION == 90" | bc)" -eq 1 ] :)

Comment: Since this is bash: `if (( $(bc <<< "$ROTATION == 90") == 1 ))`

Comment: @glennjackman, thank you for the idea. I personally prefer to use old sh syntax :) But you should use -eq 1 because == in bash is to compare strings

Answer (score 1):

Because they are strings, you can compare multiple concatenated strings against one another. Balancing values makes for simple means of handling multiple shell tests at once.

```
[ "${num#90.}${num%[!0]*}" = "90${num%[!0]*}" ] && do_it
```

But that only works if `$num` is definitely a number. You can validate an integer value for `$num` like:

```
[ "$num" -eq "$num" ]
```

Or a float like:

```
[ "${#num}${num#*.}" -ne "${num%.*}${#num}" ]
```

But `case` is usually best...

```
case ".${num##*[!-.0-9]*}" in
(.|.[!9]*|.9[!0]*|.90.*[!0]*) 
! :;;esac
```

Where outside utilities are concerned, I usually prefer `dc` to `bc` because it can be used to execute arbitrary system commands:

```
dc -e '[!echo execute arbitrary system command]s=' \
   -e '90 90.0 =='
```

Everything within the `[]` brackets is a string that is `s`aved to the array named `=` and which is executed as a `dc` command if the top two values on the main stack *(here 90 and 90.0)* `=` one another. The first `!` operator within the string is `!` operator which executes as a system command all that follows it. You can also read from input for more `dc` script to execute conditionally with the `?` operator.

The `-e`xpression syntax is a GNUism, though. You can get the same effect portably with a heredoc or echoing the commands over a pipe to its stdin.

For example:

```
! dc -e '[!kill -PIPE "$PPID"]s= 90 90.0 ==' && do_it
```

Comment: You have to more think above. 90,001 == 90 in your script.

Comment: @Costas - good point. Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare values just like a string:

```
{ printf "[ %.3f == %.3f ]\n" $ROTATION 90 | bash ; } && ROTATION_PARAMETER=" --rotate=4"
```

Or even

```
[ $(printf "%.3f == %.3f" $ROTATION 90) ] && ROTATION_PARAMETER=" --rotate=4"
```

Be attentive that some locales require `,` instead `.` as decimal separator so `$ROTATION` should be in `90,000` form.

Answer (score 0):

Consider calling a scripting language which is a bit more prepared to deal with floating point values, something akin to:

```
ROTATION=...
if $( perl -e 'use POSIX "fmod";if(fmod($ENV{ROTATION}, 90.0)<0.001) {exit(0)} else{exit(1)}' )
then...
```

(might have those exit return codes backwards)

Comment: In bash you can't do directly math operations with floating point. So you should use bc, awk, perl, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `zsh` syntax instead of `bash` syntax (by not quoting your variables), just switch to `zsh` where you can do:

```
 if (( ROTATION == 90 )); then...
```

(that would work in `ksh93` as well).

But if the value is always expressed as `90.000`, then you can also do a strong comparison:

```
 if [ "$ROTATION" = 90.000 ]; then...
```

Comment: In your last comparation `90.00` != `90.000`

Comment: @Costas, no, but that 90.00 fails the _if the value is always expressed as 90.000_ assumption.